# How to use IO.popen to write-to and read-from a child process?

Tags: windows, ruby, popen

I am running `net share` from a ruby script to delete a windows network share.

If files on the share are in use, `net share` will ask the user if they want to go ahead with the deletion, so my script needs to inspect the output from the command, and write out `Y` if it detects that `net share` is asking it for input.

In order to be able to write out to the process I open it with access flags `"r+"`.

When attempting to write to the process with `IO#puts`, I get an error:

```
Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe
```

What am I doing wrong here? (The error occurs on the line `net_share.puts "Y"`)

(The question text written out by `net share` is not followed by a newline, so I am using `IO#readpartial` to read in the output.)

```
def delete_network_share share_path

  command = "net share #{share_path} /DELETE"

  net_share = IO.popen(command, "r+")

  text = ""
  while true

    begin
      line = net_share.readpartial 1000 #read all the input that's available
    rescue EOFError
      break
    end

    text += line

    if text.scan("Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N)").size > 0
      net_share.puts "Y"
      net_share.flush  #probably not needed?
    end
  end
  net_share.close
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try w+ instead of r+

```
  Mode |  Meaning
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "r"  |  Read-only, starts at beginning of file  (default mode).
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "r+" |  Read-write, starts at beginning of file.
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "w"  |  Write-only, truncates existing file
       |  to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "w+" |  Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
       |  or creates a new file for reading and writing.
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "a"  |  Write-only, starts at end of file if file exists,
       |  otherwise creates a new file for writing.
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "a+" |  Read-write, starts at end of file if file exists,
       |  otherwise creates a new file for reading and
       |  writing.
```

Comment: Hi, I tried w+ (and also a+) but get the same problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `net share ... /delete` command to always succeed, you can pass the `/y` flag:

```
C:\>net share foo /delete /y
Users have open files on foo.  Continuing the operation will force the files closed.

foo was deleted successfully.
```

Comment: Annoying that the help for net share makes no mention of this option! Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Use `net_share.readlines` instead of begin/rescue/end.

2nd result for Googling `ruby io.popen`.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. It will lead to a dead-lock in an application that waits for input.